# Openshift (V2) app randomly shows the old welcome page instead of main index.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, deployment, openshift

I've deployed a php app (wordpress) to openshift (PHP 5.4 and MySQL gear) at http://py-inn.rhcloud.com. Its also linked to my primary domain, http://www.prahladyeri.com.

It was working fine for some time initially, but suddenly it has started showing the old welcome page titled **Welcome to your PHP application on OpenShift**. However, the site works randomly after doing a few refreshes. I've tried restarting the app from the web console multiple times, but that didn't help.

Also, I don't use github for deployment, but deploy PHP files using SFTP as mentioned [in this guide](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/).

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to see the default page when loading either of the URLs. Could your local machine possibly still have the old welcome page cached? Have you tried using an Incognito/Private browser window? Or using another machine to test?

Comment: Yep, I had tried using incognito mode and also a different browser entirely, and the welcome page used to show up randomly. It seems that the Jetpack plugin might have been the culprit here, as after disabling that plugin the site seems to be working now.